# On this day vs This day

Tags: dates

Is there any difference between:

1. On this Thursday my sister will come to visit us...
2. This Thursday my sister will come to visit us...

I feel like #2 is "more" correct, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. On this Thursday my sister will come to visit us...
> 2. This Thursday my sister will come to visit us...

Of these, only #2 is idiomatic.

You *could* simply say:

> On Thursday my sister will come to visit us.

You only need to use *either* "on" or "this", as both serve the same purpose in the sentence, that is to specify *which* Thursday you mean. When saying "*on Thursday*" there is an assumption that you mean the Thursday of *this* week and not *next* Thursday.

Note that when we say "*this* Thursday" it means the Thursday *within the current calendar week*. That day may have passed already or it may be in the future - the context of your statement should make that clear, ie:

> The event *was* this Thursday.
>   The event *is* this Thursday.